# Adding value props "lock" the selection

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I would like use react-select module for "tags". All work, but if i add value props with 2 tags (for example), i can't select other tag, my component is "locked".

Anyone have already use this module with values ?

Thank you !

Comment: you need to implement the onChange  event handler. https://react-select.com/props

Comment: Mmm okay, i need to create state too ? The default add/remove fonction don't work with value props ?

Comment: can you add your implementation?